# Decomposing the Solution Set as $x_0$+$z$, when $A $ is bounded linear operator on Hilbert Space.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let H be a Hilbert space and $A$ be a function from $D(A)=H \to R(A) \subset H$ be a bounded linear operator. Let $f \in H$ and consider the following equations:

\begin{equation}Ax=f\end{equation}
\begin{equation}Ax=0 \end{equation}

$Z_A$ is the set of all solutions of the equation $Ax=0$. Then $Z_A$ is a vector space.$\\$

a) Let $x_0$ be a solution for $Ax=f$, We need to show that the general solution for the equation $x=x_0+z$, where $z$ is an arbitrary element in $Z_A$.

My attempt:

I can just substitute $x=x_{0}+z$ into $Ax$ to get $A(x_0+z)=Ax_0=f$. But I would like to derive the expression x as a direct sum.

Let the solution set of A be defined as $$S=\{ x | Ax=f \}$$.

Let $y \in \overline{S}$, then there exists $(x_n) \in S$, such that $x_n \to x$.$\forall n$, $Ax_n=f$, since A is continuous, $Ax_n$ converges to $Ax$, and since $Ax_n=f$ for all n, $Ax=f$ as well. Thus, the solution set is closed.  A closed set in a Hilbert space is complete. Hence, the solution set is complete.
By the direct sum theorem for Hilbert spaces, I would like to decompose $S$ into direct sum.

The $N(A)$ is closed(complete). So I take the projection of every $x \in S$ on $N(A)$. I am stuck here, maybe I can write

$$S=N(A) \oplus N(A)^{\perp}$$
But am unable to proceed. Can someone please help?

Comment: If $Ax=f$ then $A(x-x_0)=Ax-A(x_0)=f-0=0$, so $x-x_0\in Z_A$  and $x=x_0+(x-x_0)$ which proves a).